# How to Append/Include

Tags: html, django

I have the following line of code in my index.html

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="contact-form">{% csrf_token %}

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="form_name" class="form-control" name="name" required="required"
                            placeholder="Your Full Name"
                            value='{% if submitbutton == "Submit" %} {{ name }} {% endif %}'>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" id="form_email" class="form-control" name="email" required="required"
                            placeholder="abc@email.com"
                            value='{% if submitbutton == "Submit" %} {{ email }} {% endif %}'>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea name="message" id="form_message" rows="5" class="form-control" required="required"
                            placeholder="Add your message."
                            value='{% if submitbutton == "Submit" %} {{ message }} {% endif %}'></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm" value="Send Message" name="Submit">

                </form>
```

and for views.py

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST['name']
        email = request.POST['email']
        message = request.POST['message']
        try:
            send_mail( name, message, email, ['cmadiam@ruthlymtspmuandaesthetics.com'], fail_silently=False)

        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
        return HttpResponse('Success! Thank you for your message.')

    return render(request, "index.html", {})
```

Now, I want add **New Inquiry from:** before the name(subject) when the email is received.

How can I do that. Is that possible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You really can't work out how to combine two strings?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm trying but I really can't work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line

```
send_mail( name, message, email, ['cmadiam@ruthlymtspmuandaesthetics.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

To

```
send_mail( "New Inquiry from: " + name, message, email, ['cmadiam@ruthlymtspmuandaesthetics.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: I already tried that before I posted my question here but I was getting an error. Maybe syntax or typo error. But when tried again your suggestion it works. Thank you!